# Was this word used under the influence of the Ring?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

It seems that everyone who dealt with the One Ring called it "**precious**".

**Did the Ring force people to use that moniker? Or was it some artefact of Middle-Earth languages as designed by Tolkien? Or merely the fact that the whole books was a re-telling by Bilbo in *The Red Book of Westmarch*, and thus he was solely responsible for the word choice?**

- First, we see **Gollum/Sméagol:**

  > 'The murder of Déagol haunted Gollum, and he had made up a defence, repeating it to his "**precious**" over and over again, as he gnawed bones in the dark, until he almost believed it. It was his birthday. Déagol ought to have given the ring to him. It had previously turned up just so as to be a present. It was his birthday present, and so on, and on.
  >
  > 'I saw him there,' answered Gandalf, 'but before that he had wandered far, following Bilbo's trail. It was difficult to learn anything from him for certain, for his talk was constantly interrupted by curses and threats. "What had it got in its pocketses?" he said. "It wouldn't say, no precious. Little cheat. Not a fair question. It cheated first, it did. It broke the rules. We ought to have squeezed it, yes precious. And we will, precious!"

  ... and countless other instances in The Hobbit and LOTR.

OK, that may be just Gollum's pet name for The One Ring, or pecularity of wording... except we also have...

- **Bilbo:**

  > 'If I am it is your fault,' said Bilbo. 'It is mine, I tell you. My own. My **precious**. Yes, my **precious**.'
  >
  > 'Well, if you want my ring yourself, say so!' cried Bilbo. 'But you won't get it. I won't give my **precious** away, I tell you.' His hand strayed to the hilt of his small sword.

OK, fine, we can write Bilbo's usage of the word on the fact that he heard Gollum use it in the cave when he found the RIng and subconsciously imprinted the word. BUT then we have ...

- **Frodo:**

  > 'Why, why wasn't it destroyed?' cried Frodo. 'And how did the Enemy ever come to lose it, if he was so strong, and it was so **precious** to him?' He clutched the Ring in his hand, as if he saw already dark fingers stretching out to seize it.
  >
  > 'What do you mean?' said Frodo. 'Surely the Ring was his **precious** and the only thing he cared for? But if he hated it, why didn't he get rid of it, or go away and leave it?'
  >
  > Frodo drew the Ring out of his pocket again and looked at it. It now appeared plain and smooth, without mark or device that he could see. The gold looked very fair and pure, and Frodo thought how rich and beautiful was its colour, how perfect was its roundness. It was an admirable thing and altogether precious.

  Now, we don't even have the "he heard it" excuse - he didn't discuss the Ring with Bilbo at any time previous!

  The third quote can be exlained by the fact that her - by then - heard Gandalf use the word when discussing Gollum... BUT the first two quotes definitely happened **before** he heard that word from Gandalf.

Not only that, but we have other characters use the word as well:

- **Tom Bombadil**:

  > 'Show me the precious Ring!' he said suddenly in the midst of the story: and Frodo, to his own astonishment, drew out the chain from his pocket, and unfastening the Ring handed it at once to Tom.
- ... and **Isildur**, as related in his scroll (recited by Gandalf)

  > But for my part I will risk no hurt to this thing: of all the works of Sauron the only fair. It is **precious** to me, though I buy it with great pain.
- ... and while at it, let's throw in an Istari (**Saruman**):

  > 'He came and laid his long hand on my arm. "And why not, Gandalf?" he whispered. "Why not? The Ruling Ring? If we could command that, then the Power would pass to us. That is in truth why I brought you here. For I have many eyes in my service, and I believe that you know where this **precious** thing now lies.'

Comment: Looks like Tolkien liked that adjective. Is it only applied to the Ring, or is it used in other contexts?

Comment: Most usage of "precious" is one of: (1) the Ring ("Precious", capitalized when used by Gollum), (2) Gollum talking to himself ("precious", uncapitalized), (3) sarcastically ("What's happened to your precious Nazgul?"), (4) referring to time ("We have already lost precious hours").  Handful of genuine usages ("veins of precious ore").

Comment: It's not true that Frodo "didn't discuss the Ring with Bilbo at any time previous" - as he tells Gandalf, Bilbo had long ago told him the (real) story of his encounter with Gollum.